# Kalman filter conceptual question

Tags: kalman-filter, gibbs, state-space-models, dlm

I'm using the function `dlmGibbsDIG` (Gibbs sampler) in the `dlm`package from R to estimate the unknown variances. The output are the unknown variances together with the (saved) sampled states.

Then the `dlmFilter` function performing the kalman filter only need as arguments the observations and the specified model (with the averaged variances gived by the output of `dlmGibbsDIG`) but I'm confused about the role of the thetas (states) simulated by the Gibbs sampler above.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're after. The states are often (but not always) unknown parameters of interest in your problem.

Comment: @Glen_b this is the case since I'm using a regression DLM but for me it's not straightforward that we only pass the estimated variances for the kalman filter.

Comment: I'm sorry, it's still not clear to me what the difficulty is.

Comment: @Glen_b well I was asking basically if the thetas in the output of the Gibbs sampler are of any use.

Comment: @AP13 whether they are of use is up to you. I have given you what they are, i.e. $p(x|\theta_i)$ which you obtain by running the Kalman filter at every iteration of the MCMC chain. The rest is up to you, unless you have a further question

Answer (score 2):

Every time you sample the prior $p(\theta_i)$ you then run the Kalman filter and obtain $p(x|\theta_i)$ - i.e. the distribution of the $\textit{states}$, conditional on the current value of $\theta$.